# How to wrap a tensorflow object as Keras layer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I would like to implement Hierarchical Multiscale LSTM as a Keras layer.
It was published [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.01704.pdf) and implemented in tensorflow [here](https://github.com/n-s-f/hierarchical-rnn).
My understanding is that there's a way to wrap such a tensorflow object in Keras as a layer. I'm not sure how complicated it is but I think it's feasible. Can you help me how to do it?

Comment: Similar unresolved topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300600/wrapping-tensorflow-for-use-in-keras

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually done by [implementing a custom Layer](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/). To be more specific, you should inherit from [keras.engine.topology.layer](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/topology.py#L180) and provide a custom implementation for the following methods (and place the TensorFlow code within them):

> - `build(input_shape)`: this is where you will define your weights. This method must set `self.built = True`, which can be done by calling
>     `super([Layer], self).build()`
> - `call(x)`:  this is where the layer's logic lives. Unless you want your layer to support masking, you only have to care about the first
>     argument passed to call: the input tensor.
> - `compute_output_shape(input_shape)`: in case your layer modifies the shape of its input, you should specify here the shape
>     transformation logic. This allows Keras to do automatic shape
>     inference.

Since you're trying to implement a recurrent layer, it would also be convenient to inherit directly from [keras.legacy.layers.recurrent](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/legacy/layers.py#L762). In this case, you probably do not need to redefine `compute_output_shape(input_shape)`. If your layer needs additional arguments, you can pass them to the `__init__` method of your custom layer.