# How do you apply layer normalization in an RNN using tf.keras?

Tags: python, tf.keras, tensorflow2.0

I would like to apply [layer normalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06450) to a recurrent neural network using tf.keras. In TensorFlow 2.0, there is a `LayerNormalization` class in `tf.layers.experimental`, but it's unclear how to use it *within* a recurrent layer like `LSTM`, at each time step (as it was designed to be used). Should I create a custom cell, or is there a simpler way?

For example, applying dropout at each time step is as easy as setting the `recurrent_dropout` argument when creating an `LSTM` layer, but there is no `recurrent_layer_normalization` argument.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a custom cell by inheriting from the `SimpleRNNCell` class, like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.activations import get as get_activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import SimpleRNNCell, RNN, Layer
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import LayerNormalization

class SimpleRNNCellWithLayerNorm(SimpleRNNCell):
    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        self.activation = get_activation(kwargs.get("activation", "tanh"))
        kwargs["activation"] = None
        super().__init__(units, **kwargs)
        self.layer_norm = LayerNormalization()
    def call(self, inputs, states):
        outputs, new_states = super().call(inputs, states)
        norm_out = self.activation(self.layer_norm(outputs))
        return norm_out, [norm_out]
```

This implementation runs a regular `SimpleRNN` cell for one step without any `activation`, then it applies layer norm to the resulting output, then it applies the `activation`. Then you can use it like that:

```py
model = Sequential([
    RNN(SimpleRNNCellWithLayerNorm(20), return_sequences=True,
        input_shape=[None, 20]),
    RNN(SimpleRNNCellWithLayerNorm(5)),
])

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="sgd")
X_train = np.random.randn(100, 50, 20)
Y_train = np.random.randn(100, 5)
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=2)
```

For GRU and LSTM cells, people generally apply layer norm on the gates (after the linear combination of the inputs and states, and before the sigmoid activation), so it's a bit trickier to implement. Alternatively, you can probably get good results by just applying layer norm before applying `activation` and `recurrent_activation`, which would be easier to implement.

Answer (score 6):

In tensorflow addons, there's a pre-built `LayerNormLSTMCell` out of the box.

See [this doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/rnn/LayerNormLSTMCell) for more details. You may have to install `tensorflow-addons` before you can import this cell.

```
pip install tensorflow-addons
```